# zlib - extract large entry

Tags: c++, c, pointers, zlib

I am using zlib library in my program code, first when I tried to extract files, it works well for small entries inside zip archive, basically I call the functions below,

```
unzOpenCurrentFile (unzFile file)

unzReadCurrentFile  (unzFile file, voidp buf, unsigned len)

unzCloseCurrentFile (unzFile file)
```

`buf` is a memory pointer (or byte array) that holds data for that entry. But when large sized entries are encountered my program simply cannot manage to create 10000000 size of array. I also tried to pass `FILE*` pointer instead of regular memory but no avail.

Comment: You can use a memory-mapped file instead of in-memory allocation.

Comment: What is `unzOpenCurrentFile`? It's not a function in `zlib`. `zlib` can't even handle zip archive files.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg it is from related thing called minizip i think.

Comment: That's only about `9MB`. You are `malloc`ing that array, not trying to stack allocate it, right?

Comment: @ildjarn that looks like a viable solution, is it correct I need to write separate code in windows and linux for memory mapped?

Comment: @ÖöTiib that is correct.

Comment: @treemonster19 : You can use [Boost.Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/libs/interprocess/) for a cross-platform solution (assuming you're using C++).

Answer (score 1):

Actually I was using this unzReadCurrentFile() function improperly which allows part by part reading in a small buffer, it returns number of bytes copied and we can loop over till it returns > 0